# Fragmented GET request when using websocket in Firefox

Tags: c#, google-chrome, firefox, websocket, handshake

I am currently developing a small websocket server in C# to handle connections from browsers.

I mostly used the code from Mozilla and Microsoft (respectively [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_server) and [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx)). Unfortunately, when I try to connect to my basic server from a browser (the script was taken from websocket.org), the GET request appears to be fragmented...

I would like to understand why the GET request is divided into two parts. Let me show you my code and the output I get from it.

Code:

```
while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
    {
        data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes,0,i);
        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);
    }
```

Output:

```
Received: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Received: 
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: null
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 2QYy54zGPPKAkNyPgFjkbw==
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
```

I also tried on Chrome to see how different it would be and by running the same code and the same script in the browser I get the following output:

```
Received: GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: 127.0.0.1
Origin: null
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: mp5oLqe/YaQAxRksoVZWKg==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_
Received: max_window_bits, x-webkit-deflate-frame
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
```

I see nothing wrong in the output with Chrome, so I don't really understand why the request is divided when using firefox...
I could merge the two parts of the request together, but if I understood the RFC6455 properly, any bad request should be dropped by the server.

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I also wrote a WebSocket server in C#, the source code may be relevant to you: http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is totally fine. Maybe Firefox is sending the information in a way (slower) you have to read twice the network buffer but this is OK. It seems it is sending the common information that never change first, and after the information about the websocket (that has to be generated each time) last, probably to reduce the "time for the first byte".

Regarding to the HTTP protocol, the header ends when there is an empty line, so as long you do not get one and the network buffer contains information (readed!=0), you can continue reading the header.

Usually, you are going to find this situation often when doing network programming. You have to continue reading until the network stream says readed=0.